# How should be the security rules while using two different firebase project accessing each other's data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using two different firebase project in two different flutter android apps. One of the firestore-database is holding some store's data and the other one is holding users Authentication-Database. Let's say, name of the first project is 'store-owners' and name of the second one is 'customer'. I want 'store-owners' data is accessible only and only if the user is registered in 'customer' project. How should be the security rules for the 'store-owners' project? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible with security rules only. You cannot authenticate users of one project from security rules of others. You would have run your own [server](https://cloud.google.com/compute) or [Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), initialize both the projects in it and then use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) access the through it.

```
// Initialize the default app
admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
var otherApp = admin.initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');

console.log(admin.app().name);  // '[DEFAULT]'
console.log(otherApp.name);     // 'other'

// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
const defaultAuth = admin.auth();
const defaultDatabase = admin.database();

// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
const otherAuth = otherApp.auth();
const otherDatabase = otherApp.database();
```

That way you can write functions which will authenticate users from your auth projects and then read the data from the project where the data is stored.
You can read more about [initializing multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) in the documenation.

To summarize the flow:

```
Call function => Authenticate User => Return relevant data
```

You would have to manually check if the user can access the requested data or not. [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) may be handy to do that.